# Why does "ELSE : " compile in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, operators

Why does this compile?

```
If Months > 1 Then

    Label.Text = Months + " Months"

Else : Months = 1

    Label.Text = Months + " Month"

End If
```

Using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`:` is a statement separator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code#to-place-multiple-statements-on-the-same-line) It's equivalent to a newline:

```
If Months > 1 Then

    Label.Text = Months + " Months"

Else

    Months = 1
    Label.Text = Months + " Month"

End If
```